# Make stopwatch alive between request

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am new to Ractive.js. I need to implement a stop watch which will be running even if I click for another page. My stopwatch is running but when I click to another page and then come back to my current page, the stopwatch is gone. What can I try next?

Here are my attempts below.

In my view:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-left">
                Stopwatch: {{#stopWatch}} {{hours}} h: {{minutes}} m: {{seconds}} s{{/stopWatch}}
            </div>
            <button id="btnStart" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" on-click="startStopWatch">Start</button>
            <button id="btnReset" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" on-click="startStopWatch">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <label class="pull-left stopWatch">  Time Spent:</label>
    </div>
```

My startStopWatch function:

```
function startStopWatch(ev, cfg) {
    var rjs = this || cfg.rjs;
    var $btn = $(ev.node);
    var btnText = $btn.text();
    var sg;

    if (btnText === 'Start') {
        $btn.html('Stop');
        sg = new cmnDt.stopWatch();
        sg.start(rjs, sg);
    } else if (btnText === 'Stop'){
        $btn.html('Start');
        sg = ev.context.sw;
        sg.stop(rjs, sg);
    }

    if (btnText === 'Reset' && ev.context.sw) {
        sg = ev.context.sw;
        sg.reset(rjs, sg);
        $('#btnStart').html('Start');
    }
}
```

My stopWatch function:

```
function stopWatch() {

        var currentSeconds = 0;
        var currentMinutes = 0;
        var currentHours = 0;
        var timer;

        function start(rjs, sw) {
            printTime(rjs, sw);
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                getTime();
                printTime(rjs, sw);
            }, 1000);
        }

        function getTime(rjs) {
            currentSeconds = currentSeconds + 1;
            if (currentSeconds === 60) {
                currentMinutes += Math.round((currentSeconds) / 60);
                currentSeconds = 0;
            } else if (currentSeconds === 60 && currentMinutes === 60) {
                currentMinutes = 0;
                currentSeconds = 0;
                currentHours += 1;
            }
        }

        function printTime(rjs, sw) { 
            rjs.set({'sw': sw, 'stopWatch.seconds': currentSeconds, 
                    'stopWatch.minutes': currentMinutes, 'stopWatch.hours': currentHours});
        }

        function stop(rjs, sw) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            printTime(rjs, sw);
            $('.stopWatch').text(' Time Spent: ' + currentMinutes + ' m : ' + currentSeconds + ' s.');
        }

        function reset(rjs, sw) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            currentSeconds = 0;
            currentMinutes = 0;
            currentHours = 0;
            printTime(rjs, sw);
        }

        return {
            start: start,
            stop: stop,
            reset: reset
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the site and come back, your whole script is initialized from start. You need to store the current value of the stop watch, and the timestamp of the current value, permanently.

For this there are two options: local [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

In ractive, here is an example how local storage is meant to be used: http://examples.ractivejs.org/todos

if you implement, say, one function `saveToStorage()` and one `initFromStorage()`, then your stopwatch may show the true time if you come back to the site. But be aware that the stop watch is not "running in some background". It is just initializing from the last moment stored. This is vital because for instance your stop watch cannot trigger events while you are on another site.

---

**Edit 15.3.16**

Find here a working stop watch in the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cw67L17e/2/

I started altering your code, but I thought then it is best to design from start. I have no time to dig into the specialities of ractivejs. But I do hope you can learn some new and useful ideas by studying it. A short hint how to use is in the fiddle at the right.

Remarks:

- Just for measuring time, you don't need a "stop watch" in the narrow sense. As you will see, it is sufficient to store time stamps. You actually need only the `prepareToLeave()` and `resume()` methods.
- I suggest don't handle seconds, minutes and hours as combined type. Just handle timestamps and convert them whenever necessary, as shown in `millisToHMS()`. Because handling millis is a generic approach that will allow many other tasks too.
- Consider the `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`.
- If you want to automatize, you could call `resume()` as soon as the document is ready, or loaded (`document.ondomcontentready`). There you have to find your ractivejs way.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to track a user how long he navigates to the application after start stop watch till stop. Some source code will help me a lot.

Comment: @SumonBappi, how does your tracking work for the user in detail? Does she/he has to click stopwatch button, navigate away, come back, click another stopwatch button, or should the stop watch be started and stopped by some events?

Comment: the user will click it. Then it should start and throughout the navigation it will not stop and will continue counting. when the user will come back to this page again then he can see how long he is on the application.

Comment: @SumonBappi, I've added a fiddle. I hope studying it's ideas will bring you forward. -- Try creating your own fiddles, and including them in the Stack Overflow questions. -- Good luck :-)

Comment: I have implemented your fiddle demo. Need to change  a lot. thanks a lot. a lot working to do to make this functional.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you've found a way :-) congratulations. Thank you for your feedback.